# Change NSURL base url to another base URL

Tags: cocoa, nsurl

I have a NSURL to a local file with no base url. I want to change the base URL to another local directory, with the relative path being in respect to that URL.
For example

```
 NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/Users/username/Desktop/Photos/Photo1.jpg"];
```

Now, say I want to change the base part to `/Users/username/Desktop/SomeFolder`, then I would want the NSString returned by `[path relativePath];` to be `"../Photos/Photo1.jpg"`

Is there an easy way to do this? I can't seem to find any NSURL methods that do this. I could go through the path components of the new base and old absolute paths to construct the relative part my self, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Seems no easy way. [Here are some codes on web can be used as a `NSString` extension.](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/101223-conversion-from-an-absolute-url-to-relative.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURL` objects are immutable so there is no way to change the base URL after creating it. Your best bet is creating a new `NSURL` instance with `URLWithString:relativeToURL:`. However, I still think what you want will not work. The docs for `-[NSURL relativePath]` state that if the receiver is an absolute URL (which your example is), this method returns the same value as `path`.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless self-promotion, [KSFileUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities) has routines to derive relative strings/URLs between two locations